# Oculus Quest on Unity Editor 2019.3.0f6 not debug

Tags: unity-game-engine, debugging, oculus, oculusquest

i have running my Unity whit hand tracking application in my oculus Quest, but i need debug this un my Unity Editor.

I have Unity 2019.3.0f6 and the featured for this version have a connection vía oculus link, but i cant show the app in the editor. Help!!!

Comment: As far as I know, live Unity-Editor-debugging for Quest via e.g. Oculus Link is unfortunately not possible yet. It would be very useful.

Comment: The Unity version 2019.3.0.f6 can tests could be done through the oculus link, but in my setup i cant, maybe is for use, Maybe it is because you are using the charging cable and not the oculus link.